# How to set color of title bar of an app in Recent Applications

Tags: android

How does Android decide what color to use for the title bar of the application preview in the Recent Applications view (the view of all recent applications you see when you press the square button on 5.0 devices).

I ask because I have a launcher icon that I really like but it's the same color as my applications primary color used on the Applications own titlebar/actionbar/toolbar. That makes sense these days now that the launcher icon never shows up on app's own titlebar when using material design guidelines. But it is pretty much invisible on the title bar of the app preview in the Recent Applications list.

I'd like to change the Recent Apps titlebar color without changing the color of the APplication's title bar. (The duplicate question somebody assigned to this question provides an answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean just change the titlebar's color you can use toolbar instead of actionbar.
then

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.myToolbar);
toolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#dd4b39"));
```

can change the color?